# Insert html tags

Tags: html, vba, ms-word

I've several hundred Word documents that I need to insert html tags as per below:

a short **bold text** line

becomes

a short `<b>`bold text`</b>` line

Does anyone know the easiest and most efficient way of doing this?

Currently looking at doing a macro.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? If we know what you're trying to do in the long run it will be easier to get you a solution.

Comment: I have a bunch of files that get submitted to a web site, and the contents of the word files gets dumped into a description field. Need to add html styling tags for bold, italic and unordered lists so it formats nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution I found, tested with Word 2010:

In the search and replace dialog,

Leave the Find what: field blank
In the Replace with: put `<b>^&</b>`
    In the Format -> Font section, select Bold
    Replace All

This will put the tags around your bold text. Then you can just copy it to put it in the webpage.

#### Edit:

Alternatively, you could use Wildcards with search and replace, using the pattern `\<b\>(*)\</b\>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, anybody can use it, put the code in VBA module and run it, the macro will automatically add bold in ms Word.

```vb
Sub Bo()
'Finding Bold Text
Dim boldWord As String
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
With doc.Content.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Font.Bold = True
.Execute
While .Found
boldWord = .Parent.Text
.Parent.Text = "<b>" & boldWord & "</b>"
.Execute
Wend
End With
doc.Content.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End Sub
```